# Eat or be eaten?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I've a question about friends script and I don't know the meaning. It seems that it should be an idiom.

The sentence is

> Mrs. Green: Monica! You look gorgeous! Last time I saw you, it was eat or be eaten.

What does 'Eat or be eaten' mean here?

Comment: Can you give any more information about the context of the remark?

Comment: Perhaps it is an ironic way to say Monica has lost weight, as she had previously seemed to hold the philosophy of “eat or be eaten” and she did not want to be eaten. But more context would indeed help.

Comment: I've seen the idiom used in the sense of "oppress other people or they will oppress you", but this doesn't fit the above context, so I suspect it's intended as a sort of pun.

Answer (score -1):

I'd speculate that the phrase originates with social Darwinism, describing a world in which only the fittest survive. You are either an eater, or you are food. I think Mrs. Green has misspoken and insulted Monica. To imply that "eat or be eaten" is connected to her looks implies that when last she saw Monica, she was in a state indicating a kind of primitive survival mode ("She looked desperate").

Comment: Actually, in the story arc of the show "Friends," Monica was portrayed as being obese in the past. I believe the "eat or be eaten" comment was a joke relating to her previous weight problem.

Comment: I agree with RobJarvis. Though, the phrase, in another context, could be a compliment. That depends on how it is said, and to who. Some magazine advertisements will portray the model with a predatory, cat-like look. Some may call it “looking fierce”.

Comment: I yield to a superior knowledge of the teevee show "Friends".